# Xcode: Tabbed workflow

Tags: xcode, tabs, behavior

In Xcode I use a task-based tabbed workflow (a separate tab for editing, UI/Modeling, building, debugging, etc.). I accomplish this using Behaviors (see the Custom section in the attached screen shot). When I create a new Project I use press ⌘+1, ⌘+2, etc. to quickly setup all of my task tabs.

My issue is that when I do this for a newly created Project all of the tabs display the source, storyboards, etc. from my most recently open Project. How often do you think this is useful or the desired behavior? I realize that one of the great things about tabs is that they remember their state and this is helpful. But as far as the source files that are initially displayed, this is a real pain. I do not want to see files from other (generally unrelated) projects.

Now what I just did as an experiment was open Project A and setup all of my tabs and ensured that each tab contained a source file from Project A. Then I quit Xcode and moved Project A a new location on the file system. When I opened Project B and created all of my tabs they were, as desired, empty.

I realize that I'm just going to receive the canonical "File a Radar" here but in the off chance that there is a workaround (NOT moving files) or a preference I could set, I figured I'd at least ask.

Thanks in advance,
CS

[image]

Comment: Received information from Apple - there is no way to do this. I've entered a Radar feature request.

Comment: https://devforums.apple.com/message/756180#756180